# Node.js + Mysql DateTime is saved one hour earlier in database

Tags: mysql, node.js, datetime

I'm new in Node.js.
I'm working on a Node.js project which uses express, squelize. moment.js and mysql. Mysql gets build in Docker.
The problem is, when I want to save a datetime in the database, the time will be saving 1 hour earlier!

This is the code that I use

```
const userTimezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
const userLocalTime = moment.tz(moment(), userTimezone);
```

How can I solve the problem?